# How to add some lines to the project's csproj file after installing a nuget

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I created a library which will be turned into a nuget that will run on the target assemblies.
Let's call it **NugLib**.

**Goal:**

What I want is to add2,3 lines to the target assembly after it installed the NugLib.
NugLib (the library) had a .targets file which copied some files into the target assembly.

I want to be able to add some lines to the project (the .csproj file) Not sure if it can be done via the .targets .props .nuspec or the lib's csproj during/after the installing nuget automatically.

Want to add these 3 lines to the target assembly (the nuget consumer):

```
  <Content Include=".pack\*.*;.pack\**;.pack\**\*" />
  <Import Project="build\build.targets" />
  <Import Project=".pack\package.csproj" Condition="Exists('.pack\package.csproj')" />
```

Comment: As far as I know, the targets file under Build folder is a function file to import some other content files into the main project, did it also a content targets file? Also, if you want to use this targets file, it should be named as <package_id>.targets, in your side, it should be `NugLib.targets` file.See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package).

Comment: Yes @PerryQian-MSFT the name of the targets is right and is doing its job, but seems I can achieve what I wanted via nuspec file, which someone else told me in another site. seems you both also referred to the same link, thanks.

Comment: Fine, thanks, I am familiar with the .targets file, and the targets file is doing is main mission right which was to copy the needed contents and directories to the location of the target project. BTW seems nuspec also could do the same job as well, if you want to provide an answer so please let me know how can I change the project's ID/Title which I defined it earlier in the package.csproj with some extra info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add some lines to the project's csproj file after installing a
>   nuget

Since you use a net standard 2.1 class library, you can use an easier way.

You can follow these steps:

**1)**  create such project structure:

[image]

**Note**: you cannot use `import="xxxx.csproj"`, it is illegal and one main csproj file cannot  import another csproj file of the same level. Instead, you should change to use `package.targets` rather than `packages.csproj`.

**2)** you should create a file named `<package_id>.targets` in the build folder so that it can import such node in your main `project.csproj` when you install such nuget package.

In `NugLib.targets` file:

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="..\contentFiles\any\any\build\build.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\contentFiles\any\any\package.targets" Condition="Exists('..\contentFiles\any\any\package.targets')" /> 
</Project>
```

**3)** upload NugLib project and then add these in `NugLib.csproj` file:

```
  <ItemGroup>  
     <Content Update=".pack\**" Pack="true" IncludeInPackage="true" PackagePath="content\any\any\;contentFiles\any\any\;;">
    </Content>
    <Content Update="build\build.targets" Pack="true" IncludeInPackage="true" PackagePath="content\any\any\;contentFiles\any\any\;;">    
    </Content>
    <None Update="build\NugLib.targets" Pack="true"  PackagePath="build\NugLib.targets" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**4)** Right-click on your project and select **Pack**, then the new NugLib nuget package will exist under `bin\Debug\xxx.nupkg`.

**Besides**, if you want to rename the package, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli#set-properties).

These files will automatically add in your main project. In net framework project, like this:

[image]

In net core project, it is under `obj\ConsoleApp1.csproj.nuget.g.targets`

[image]

To add project's ID/Title, you can set these properties in `NugLib.csproj` file directly:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PackageId>AppLogger</PackageId>
  <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  <Authors>your_name</Authors>
  <Company>your_company</Company>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at first glance, there might be something to try so please give a time to me to try some parts, but there are some points which I can mention now, first about PackageId and other info, the NugLib project already defined all in the Package.csproj which acts a generic packaging tool here, the fact is I want to set them based on the target lib (which will install the NugLib) I want the PackageId change to "ConsumerProject" based on that project's name. Will try all the parts and provide feedback, thanks

Comment: Let me continue this discussion here, based on every part I see, and will ask related questions here, you said "one main csproj file cannot import another csproj file of the same level" but it was working as expected, If I move those data to package.targets what may be different? Could define the exact same way? Any benefit to that?

Comment: And about this: "Since you use a net standard 2.1 class library, you can use an easier way." Easier way in comparison with what approach? the nupsec way you mean?

Comment: My next question, is 'content' and 'contentFiles' a known/reserved word here, or you used it just as an example?

Comment: Net standard project has an easy way to create  nuget package without using nuspec file.Actually, in my side and the normal behavior is to import a targets or props file and we do not import a csproj file in another csproj file. It may have some implicit problems.And move to `packages.targets` is the same as before because of using the same xml node `<Import>`. You do not worry too much about it.

Comment: For net framework project, nuget will import the content files from content folder into the main project while new sdk project(net standard or net core), nuget will import the content files from ContentFiles folder into the net core project. This is the nuget mechanism. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files).

Comment: Can we continue the discussion in the chat?

Comment: I got this error after doing all your steps: https://postimg.cc/5HC83FtX

Comment: Also to make you see what I have done and knowing a similar structure placed the code in GitHub: https://github.com/KKacer/MSBuild11

Comment: Also currently seems none of the files were moved.

Comment: Hello @Perry Qian-MSFT , guess you back, can we continue this in a chat?

Comment: Sure, you should check your nuget zip package first. Make sure that these files exist in the folder structure in the nupkg package. Second, every time,when you reinstall the new  version package, you should delete the old wrong nuget package under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`. Then restart VS Instance to test it.

Comment: Thanks, I had several trials, in some I saw part of the files needed to be copied and in some those were missed, but guess the current version should be closest to the steps you provided, I also found that those 'any' you mentioned could be like known words, I tried those earlier and they didn't work at that time, so commented them, but guess now again I should uncomment those parts.

Comment: I still don't know why the chat option isn't enabled here

Comment: First, in NugLib project,  please move the `<Import Project="build\build.targets" />` on the top of the `nuglib.csproj` file. Second, add any\any to specify the framework version to the package so that the content files will be imported. Like this:`PackagePath="content\any\any\.pack\;contentFiles\any\any\.pack\;;"`

Comment: Tried with any/any earlier, though thought those are just some hints to use any file. but sure will bring back the any section, wasn't any other issues there?

Comment: will provide feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216417/discussion-between-kasrak-and-perry-qian-msft).

Comment: Please check the chat, I have added the latest feedback there.

Comment: You can check my small sample and if it can add these import lines into your goal project without errors. You can consider accepting it.

Comment: Hello @Perry, came back now, where is the small sample? can you post the link in the chat?

Comment: Found the answer and what I should do now. feel free to check the chat to see the last comments, thanks Ms Perry.